# MySQL Database won't connect

Tags: php, mysql

I copied a seemingly simple database connect function from one file to another and now it won't work. It's driving me a little mad:

```
<?php
//connect-to-database
function database_connect(){
    $username="test";
    $password="password123";
    $hostname="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    $db_name="database";        
    //connection to the database
    $dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password,$db_name) or die ("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    return $dbhandle;       
}
function get_row($id){
global $db;
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID='".$id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     // create a variable for each item
     $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
     $first = $row->first;
     $last  = $row->last;
     $email = $row->email;
{    

$db = database_connect();
get_row(1); //get a test user with id of 1
echo "Hello".$first;
```

Comment: might wanna clean up the other file too

Comment: your function doesn't return anything so doing `if (!database_connect())` makes no sense.

Comment: Try to connect not inside a function. What happens then?

Comment: mysql_connect is deprecated, you have to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)

Comment: Code updated to mysqli. Still not working.

Comment: pretty sad when you get downgraded but no one can help. This is a well formatted and researched request.

Comment: Is the userID column a string? If not, quoting the value should fail. Have you looked at the part of the MySQLi manual that describes parameterized queries?

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php, take a crack at using prepared statements, and then, if you are still stuck, try asking a new question. If you can edit this question to be more complete, you might get it reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you dont have dbhandle set as a variable neither connect inside get_row function. To reduce excessive connections I would recommend storing dbhandle as a variable and access that within get_row using the global scope.

So your code should be like this

```
<?php
//connect-to-database
function database_connect(){
    $username="test";
    $password="password123";
    $hostname="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    $db_name="database";        
    //connection to the database
    $dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password,$db_name) or die ("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    return $dbhandle;       
}

function get_row($id){
global $db;
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID='".$id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
     // create a variable for each item
     return $row;
   }
   else{
     return false;
   }
}    

$db = database_connect();
$row = get_row(1); //get a test user with id of 1
$first = $row->first;
$last  = $row->last;
$email = $row->email;

echo "Hello".$first;
```

Comment: I just updated my code to mysqli and also included the function to call a row. Still not able to get this to work.

Comment: i have updated my answer, refer to it now

Comment: Thanks for your efforts on this but even if I copy yours out, it still does not work.

Comment: Oh how could have I missed that, actually the result is not fetched yet, I have updated my answer again to fetch object using mysqli_fetch_object

Comment: This is a tough one. Still not working...

Comment: not really, even i had replicated some errors on your code, so your get_row() function was wrong, and it didnt return anything neither had a function closure. I have again checked it, if you can provide the exact error that you get then it would have been easier to focus on that area, right now you would be getting a fatal error from PHP side if the code is as it is in the question. Anyway update your code with my answer again and check.

Comment: I have updated it to what I currently have. This seems as though it should be easy. Are the functions causing the issue? Should I do this without functions?

Comment: update your code with my latest change to answer. i have fixed some errors on the get_row function.